# Error: unable to create icon mask image from image named "AppIconMask.png" at scale 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I  am getting **"___createApplicationIconFromImage_block_invoke: Error: unable to create icon mask image from image named "AppIconMask.png" at scale 2.0"**
error while opening a PDF Viewer using iOS Cordova phone-gap based application

```
 Unknown activity items supplied: (
    "QLPrintPageRenderer: 0x187bc720>",
    "UIPrintInfo: 0x1c0b51f0>"
)
```

//While executing present View :

```
 [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:NO];
```

Can anyone please tell me why this error arose in iOS phone-gap based or if anyone facing the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved me issue. It is working fine now after following below steps

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6742087?start=0&tstart=0

To troubleshoot this issue where your iPhone is unresponsive, please follow the steps outlined below:

```
1. If a single application is not responding or stops responding when it opens, you can force it to close.

2. If the device is unresponsive or if certain controls aren't working as expected, restart your device.

3. If the device remains unresponsive or does not turn on (or power on), reset your device.
```